# “error: no init found. Try passing init=bootarg” error after power failure during boot

Tags: boot

```
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target file system doesn't have /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg

Busybox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu7) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs) _
```

I tried passing `init=bootarg` in linux by editing the boot option in grub but it doesn't help.. I tried to boot the live cd trying to get my files but as I mount the volume it goes forever...how should I fix this?

edit: 
I tried using fsck but it says,

```
filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by other program?
fsck: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda1
```

Are there any low level system utilities for linux that can be booted (a little similar to msdos' command.com ) so that I will use fsck under it to make sure that the device is not busy or in use?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into the LiveCD again, launch `GParted`, and check the partition (click on the partition and choose *Partition → Check*). If you see any errors, save them and copy them here.

Comment: it says: Device or resource is busy.. I tried using fsck..but same result..

Comment: Is the partition really unmounted (see output of `mount`)? Are you using a LiveCD or LiveUSB? Which version of Ubuntu? BTW I think `busybox` (see your original post and the prompt) supports basic commands like `mount`, `umount` and `fsck`.

Comment: filesystem is not mounted...I'm using a LiveCD (ubuntu 10.10)... I tried mounting it w/ busybox..but still same as I do it on ubuntu terminal...Mount executes but never returns... Fortunately I can still use debugfs to backup my important files but I still want my old system back...

Comment: I just don't understand why I can't be mounted while debugfs can still open it..Also,, isn't the '/' (root dir) used when the booting stopped, is still the root of the disk image loaded by initrd?? So /sbin/init is still from the disk image. Could it be that the disk image is damaged?

Comment: Have you tried `fsck`ing the partition from the `busybox` prompt?

Comment: there's no fsck in busy box...

Comment: Just try a different LiveCD or alternate CD and check the partition again. You can also check the process which is blocking the unmount by running `sudo lsof /dev/sda1`.

Comment: too late...hahaha I got it reformatted....thanks anyway...

Comment: $ sudo lsof /dev/sda1 returns "
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /cow
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/me/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete."

Answer (score 1):

You need check the filesystem on the Hard Disk Drive.

1. Run LiveCD, open terminal
2. In terminal, type

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   This command display your partitions
3. Then

   ```
   sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/partition_on_disk
   ```

   for example

   ```
   sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda2
   ```
4. On every `fix?` answer `y`.
5. Reboot system

Source [here](http://itprofi.in.ua/blog/software/43-ne-zagrujaetsia-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was a victim of "Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init". I tried using fsck, but it didn't work because of the following problem.

fsck: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda1
Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?

So here is the solution:

Boot from Live Ubuntu CD.

->remove the first inode.

```
sudo debugfs -w /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
debugfs: clri <8>
debugfs: quit
```

->Restart into live cd again. and do

```
sudo fsck -yv /dev/sda1
```

It will work this time.

Cheers